# How can I create this transition effect

Tags: mixing, synthesis, filter

I don't know what this popular transition effect that DJ's use is called, but I'd like to know how can I recreate it with common DJ programs (like Traktor)

The effect I mean is the kind of noise in addition to the main track(s) that seems to increase its pitch over time. As an example, in this video the effect lasts from 46:21 to 46:30

Start:

Answer (score 1):

That is white noise with a subtle filter and volume sweep on in.

Try a low pass filter on white noise with a 24db slope, and bump up the filter resonance a little under half way. Then slowly sweep it from like 2khz to 20khz while also slowly increasing the volume.

Good Luck!